# Rounding issue with sp_executesql on dynamic select clause with calculation

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, dynamic-sql, sp-executesql

I am facing a problem with output from `sp_executesql` in a stored procedure in SQL Server. Below is the part of the stored procedure:

```
DECLARE @RET_Amt as NUMERIC(18,2)
DECLARE @v_Select nvarchar(200)
SET @v_select = 'SELECT  @RET_Amt=(14315.00-10420.00) /10420.00'
exec sp_executesql @v_select,N'@RET_Amt numeric output', @RET_Amt output;
SELECT 'Return Value' = @RET_Amt
```

This returns an output of `0.00` which is not correct. When we just execute select clause on prompt:

```
select (14315.00-10420.00) / 10420.00
```

Output is : 0.3738003838

So `sp_executesql` is rounding the result. Can someone help me to get value without rounding with `sp_executesql`? My stored procedure is creating the dynamic select clause and building the query. So I have to go with `sp_executesql`.

Thanks for any input!

Answer (score 2):

You're not properly specifying the precision and scale on your return parameter - if you don't specify anything, the default is `numeric(18,0)` - which means **no digits** after the decimal point - hence the rounding.

Try this instead:

```
DECLARE @RET_Amt as NUMERIC(18,2)
DECLARE @v_Select nvarchar(200)

SET @v_select = 'SELECT  @RET_Amt = (14315.00 - 10420.00) / 10420.00'

EXEC sp_executesql @v_select, N'@RET_Amt NUMERIC(18,2) OUTPUT', @RET_Amt OUTPUT;

SELECT  'Return Value' = @RET_Amt
```

In the `EXEC` statement, you need to define the `@RET_Amt` to be `NUMERIC(18,2)` (like you defined the variable already) - not just `numeric` ...

Comment: Thank you so much Marc. It was great help.

Comment: @Rakesh: if this answer helped you solve your problem, then please [**accept this answer**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5234/153998). This will show your appreciation for the people who *spent their own time to help you*.